# VBA Application.run "this workbook" property syntax

Tags: vba, excel

I'm building a macro which calls other macros in the same WB and the VBA references "'file name.xlsm' my macro" and I want it to access the this.workbook property instead.
What's the Syntax for that?

the code I have is:

```
Application.Run _
        "'Player Transaction Report sorted by name.xlsm'!Generate_tables"
```

Comment: Not sure what do You mean, but to call a macro from one module in the same workbook (if module is not private) but another or the same module use:
Call myMacroName

Comment: And to add some more info if e. g. You have Your macro in another module or it is in a worksheet object then You can call this macro by adding place name, e. g. for module1 macro called test then: Call module1.test ; and e. g. worksheet1 (code behind) and macro called ws1Test then: Call worksheet1.ws1Test and so on.

Comment: You nailed it! thanks man, works a charm! "call" was exactly what I needed

Comment: @Mikisz FYI `Call` is a deprecated, obsolete keyword. Instead of `Call Sheet1.DoSomething` you can just write `Sheet1.DoSomething`.

Answer (score 0):

If `Generate_Tables` is a public procedure written in a standard module (say, `Module1`), then it's globally scoped and you can invoke it like this:

```
Generate_Tables
```

Or you can qualify it with the module name:

```
Module1.Generate_Tables
```

In other words, the syntax for invoking any of your own `Sub` procedures is exactly the same as that for invoking any other `Sub` procedure in any referenced type library.

When you do this:

```
Application.Run "DoSomething"
```

You're invoking the `Run` method on the `Application` object, and passing `"DoSomething"` as a parameter to that method.